# Different results when using calculated member or expression

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I have a result I don't understand. Using a simple MDX-Query

```
SELECT
  {([Measures].[Anzahl Bewerbungen], [Dim Bewerbungsstatus].[Ergebnis].&[Einstellung])} on 0,
  [Dim Bewerbungsstatus].[Bewerbungsstatus].&[17] on 1
FROM Bewerbungen
```

i get the following (correct) result

```
               Anzahl Bewerbungen
                  Einstellung
Auftrag ab          (NULL)
```

However, if i use the column expression in a calculated member

```
WITH MEMBER [Einstellungen] AS
  ([Measures].[Anzahl Bewerbungen], [Dim Bewerbungsstatus].[Ergebnis].&[Einstellung])
SELECT
  {[Einstellungen]} on 0,
  [Dim Bewerbungsstatus].[Bewerbungsstatus].&[17] on 1
FROM Bewerbungen
```

i get different results

```
             Einstellungen
Auftrag ab        668
```

I expected these two queries to be the same, but obviously they're different. Where is my fault?

**EDIT**

I managed to get the same result with definig a `SET` instead of a `MEMBER` with

```
WITH SET [Einstellungen] AS
  ([Measures].[Anzahl Bewerbungen], [Dim Bewerbungsstatus].[Ergebnis].&[Einstellung])
SELECT
  {[Einstellungen]} on 0,
  [Dim Bewerbungsstatus].[Bewerbungsstatus].&[17] on 1
FROM Bewerbungen
```

Anyhow, my question still is unanswered: why is this different?